# ¿Por qué Ajax no reconoce una solicitud y devuelve "Uncaught ReferenceError: show is not defined"?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http

Tengo este código **Ajax**:

```
$.ajax({
  crossDomain: true,
  url: ' http://api.tvmaze.com/shows',
  success : function (shows, textStatus, xhr) {
    shows.forEach(function (shows) {
      var article = template
      .replace(':name:', show.name)
      .replace(':img:',show.image.medium)
      .replace(':summary:',show.summary)
      .replace(':img alt',show.name)
      $('Body-app')
       .find('.tv-shows')
       .append($(article))
    })
  }
})
```

y me sale este error en consola de Chrome:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: show is not defined

show se refiere a:

```
.replace(':name:', show.name)
```

El código consecuente también tiene problemas **¿Cómo lo soluciono?**

Comment: show no existe.. existe shows, que es el parámetro que le llega a la función del foreach

Comment: cambia el shows de function(shows) por function(show) y ya lo tienes, siempre que te vengan bien los datos.

Comment: Es un error tipográfico, se resuelve borrando una `s`, como ha dicho @F.bernal. Guardar esta pregunta no tiene ninguna utilidad en el sitio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu error es el nombre que le estar pasando al parámetro del `callback` que devuelve `forEach`, debería ser `show` y no `shows`, ahora como estás usando **jQuery** te recomiendo usar mejor [$.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

```
$.ajax({
  crossDomain: true,
  url: ' http://api.tvmaze.com/shows',
  success : function (shows, textStatus, xhr) {
    shows.forEach(function (show) {
      var article = template
      .replace(':name:', show.name)
      .replace(':img:',show.image.medium)
      .replace(':summary:',show.summary)
      .replace(':img alt',show.name)
      $('Body-app')
       .find('.tv-shows')
       .append($(article))
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: *ahora como estás usando jQuery te recomiendo usar mejor $.each()*  ... No optimizará nada en este caso, y puede que hasta sea más lento que la función nativa de Javascript, que es la que está usando.

Comment: La solución ya estaba en el comentario, no merece la pena una respuesta...